# MySQL incrementing variable in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

So I have a routine that does (pseudo-code):

```
$rows = SELECT DISTINCT a, b FROM t1;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    SET @i = 0;
    UPDATE t1 SET c_index = @i := (@i+1)
      WHERE a = $row[a] and b = $row[b] ORDER BY c DESC;
}
```

The point is to number a subset of rows by the way they are sorted. Works fine, but this is update runs thousands of times so is pretty slow. To speed it up I want to put it in a stored procedure.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE vA, vB, i INT;
  DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT a, b
    FROM t1 WHERE ...;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

  OPEN cur1;
  WHILE done = 0 DO
    FETCH cur1 INTO vA, vB;
    IF done = 0 THEN
      SET i=0;
      UPDATE t1
        SET c_index = i:= (i+1)
        WHERE a = vA AND b = vB
        ORDER BY c DESC;
    END IF;
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

However, when creating the above procedure MySQL says there is a syntax error at "i := ...". If I use a session variable for 'i' it works (@i). Using a session variable in a stored procedure is not very elegant. How can the above stored procedure be fixed without using a session variable for 'i'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED:** Since MySQL cursors are not updatable (read-only) there is no much sense of using one in your case. Almost everything you can possibly think of can be expressed just by pure `UPDATE` statement(s).

If `(a, b, c)` are unique you can do it this way

```
UPDATE table1 t JOIN 
(
  SELECT a, b, c, 
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
      FROM table1
     WHERE a = t.a
       AND b = t.b
       AND c > t.c
  ) rnum
    FROM table1 t
) s
    ON t.a = s.a
   AND t.b = s.b
   AND t.c = s.c
   SET t.c_index = s.rnum
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae240/1)** demo

or if you happen to have some sort of `id` (e.g. `auto_increment` column) then

```
UPDATE table1 t JOIN 
(
  SELECT id, 
  (
    SELECT 1 + COUNT(*)
      FROM table1
     WHERE a = t.a
       AND b = t.b
       AND c > t.c
  ) rnum
    FROM table1 t
) s
    ON t.id = s.id
   SET t.c_index = s.rnum
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1a5d7/1)** demo

Comment: No, incrementing first does not help since the increment need to happen for every row, and your final solution uses session variables which I want to avoid.

Comment: @ColinM do you have some sort of `id` in your table (e.g.an autoincrement column)?

Comment: @ColinM or is the combination `(a, b, c)` UNIQUE?

Comment: There is no surrogate key, the primary key is (a, b, c) in my example. The only issue is I want to avoid using a session variable and can't find a syntax that works with a declared local variable.

Comment: Then first example in the updated answer should do it, replacing by itself the whole procedure, and doesn't use variables. So did it help after all?

Comment: That is a very cool approach, but it will run one "select count" query for every row. The table currently has over 200k rows and it is slowly growing.. So while it looks like it would work I don't think it is worth the trade-off vs the stored procedure which does one select total. Is there no way to do the stored procedure without using a session variable?

Comment: No there is no way to use local variables in a sql statement because of their limited scope. 200k of rows is almost nothing nowadays. And with proper indexing (which you should have since `(a,b,c)` is a PK) it should work just fine. Well anyway decision is yours. And if you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to upvote/accept it.

Comment: While I agree 200k rows is nothing, I don't agree that O(n) sub-queries for an update is ideal. Anyway, I think you also gave the answer I was looking for which is the local variables cannot be used in the UPDATE query. I think I will use a session variable with a prefix to try to avoid conflict. Thanks for your answer, I definitely hadn't thought of doing it that way and I'm sure that technique will be useful in the future!